# Display ALT attributes on hover for every LI element

Tags: jquery

using this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1<img src="#" alt="photo 1"/></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2<img src="#" alt="photo 2"/></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3<img src="#" alt="photo 3"/></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using this Jquery gives me only the alt from the first LI element for all 3:

```
 var altText = $( "#actioncall_buttons li > a > img" ).attr( "alt" );   

    $( "#actioncall_buttons li" ).hover(function() {

        $( this ).append( "<span>"+altText+"</span>" );
    }, function() {

        $( "#actioncall_buttons li span" ).remove();

    });
```

How to show the alt for each specific li element?

Comment: Put your `var altText = $( "#actioncall_buttons li > a > img" ).attr( "alt" );  ` inside the hover loop and use `$(this)` instead of `$( "#actioncall_buttons li > a > img" )`

Comment: Use a `title` attribute instead. The browser will display it after a brief delay with no scripting required, or combine this with any of the [various 'tooltip' plugins](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip) for jQuery to style the tooltip to your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. you should be Getting alt text on hover.

```
$( "#actioncall_buttons li" ).hover(function() {
var altText = $( this ).find("img").attr( "alt" );   
    $( this ).append( "<span>"+altText+"</span>" );
}, function() {
    $( "#actioncall_buttons li span" ).remove();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hS7Y3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get their alt attribute using

```
$( "#actioncall_buttons li > a > img" ).attr( "alt" )
```

This is because your jQuery selector selects multiple alt attributes. Each of them with a different content. What jQuery does in such cases is to return the first it finds.

So if you want to access all different alt tags you could acccess them like this:

```
var images = $( "#actioncall_buttons li > a > img" );
$(images).each(function() { 
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
});
```